# How to get R Matrix::image `cuts` to work properly?

Tags: r

I have a matrix that I'd like to visualize.  I'm using the `image` method provided by the `Matrix` built-in package to accomplish this.

For example:

```
image(matrix(seq(1:100),10,10))
```

[image]

As you can see, this does not accurately reflect the full range of values.  It appears that the `Matrix::image` method applies some sort of binning to the values before making the plot.  [The docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/image-methods.html) show a `cuts` parameter that defaults to `15`.  It's hard to tell, but it looks like there are maybe about 15 bins in this image, so I think that this is the culprit.  However, when I attempt to pass a different value for this parameter, I get an error:

```
image(matrix(seq(1:100),10,10), cuts=255)
```

Results in:

```
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
  "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
5: In box(...) : "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
6: In title(...) : "cuts" is not a graphical parameter
```

And does not alter the displayed image.

How can I change the number of "bins" or "cuts" with a `Matrix::image` in R?

Comment: `image(matrix(seq(1:100),10,10),  col =  gray.colors(100, start = 1, end = 0))` I would say there is no binning when you provide enough colors

Comment: hmmmm...  where did you find the documentation for the `col` parameter?

Comment: ...nm.... I think the docs trace to [the panel function here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/panel.levelplot.html)

Comment: as far as I could find image is from package graphics. `Matrix` variants are used for some fancy types of matrices such as `dgCMatrix`, `dgRMatrix`, `dgTMatrix` and so on. for an ordinary `matrix` just `graphics::image` is used: `showMethods(image, includeDefs = TRUE, inherited = FALSE)`